# MSBuild Post Event works in Visual Studio 2012 but not 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have the following post build event which works in VS 2012, but throws and error in VS 2013.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
echo "Building In Debug No Minification".
) ELSE (
$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe "$(ProjectDir)MSBuild\MSBuildSettings.xml"
)
```

Here is the error I receive in VS 2013:

```
Error   109 The command "if Debug == Debug (
echo "Building In Debug No Minification".
) ELSE (
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Development\dir1\dir2\MSBuild\MSBuildSettings.xml"
)" exited with code 255.
```

The post build event is doing minification and obfuscation with YUI Compressor.

Comment: You haven't posted details for the part that's failing. Have you tried running the external step manually to debug the problem?

Comment: It does not fail while running it in the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSBuild path has changed in VS2013.  It now has spaces.  Which requires you to use double-quotes around the path name, even if the command doesn't actually get used.  Fix:

```
  "$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe" "$(ProjectDir)MSBuild\MSBuildSettings.xml"
```